# Does intelligence influence Witch Doctor minion damage?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

The "Soul Harvest" ability harvests the souls of up to five surrounding enemies, upping your intelligence by 28 (at the base level) for each. This means that right now, I can quadruple my intellgence for 30 seconds by using that skill.

Does that mean that I quadruple the damage bonus that my hounds and spiders receive, too? Or do they receive no bonus from intelligence at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your hounds and spiders do damage based on your current DPS, which is influenced by your intelligence. Soul Harvest will increase all of your damage output as a Witch Doctor, from all of your spells.

It really wouldn't be very good otherwise.

Comment: Hovering over your Int stat in the character window will show you just how much bonus damage you're getting.

Comment: You sure?On D3 site it is still stated that it is as % of weapon damage http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/active/summon-zombie-dogs

Comment: @Arremer That's exactly what % of weapon damage means. Your "damage" is shown on your inventory, and skills deal a percentage of that damage. It's all normalized, so something that does 115% damage will do 15% more damage than something that dose 100% damage on average.